# JQuery get value of elements selected by Attribute-Starts-With-Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get each value of each element selected by regex.

Specifically, i have a list of inputs like this, generated by a loop

```
 <input type="file" name="file[{$some_file.id}]">
```

anh i am trying to get the value of each input by jquery like this

```
$("input[name^='file[']").change(function () {
  //get each input value
})
```

I tried `this.val()` but obviously it did not work. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: Don't see any regex. You appear to be using the [attribute-starts-with  selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: Oh yes, that is what i meant, edited, sorry for not using precise words :D. Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler `this` binding is the element itself, not a `jQuery` object.

From [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler)

> When jQuery calls a handler, the `this` keyword is a **reference to the element** where the event is being delivered

so you want

```
this.value
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Value

```js
$('input[name^="file["]').on('change', function() {
  console.info(this.name, this.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file[0]">
<input type="file" name="file[1]">
<input type="file" name="file[2]">
<input type="file" name="not-this-one">
```

---

Alternatively, wrap the element in a `jQuery` object like this and use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method

```
$(this).val()
```

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed and helpful answer